# Apache Virtual host shows blank page over Internet, works fine locally

Tags: php, apache, digital-ocean, mod-fcgid, suexec

*Please do not answer until you read the full question :)*

In a freshly created DigitalOcean CentOS 6.5 (64 bit) server, I tried creating two Apache virtual hosts -  `www.example-rose.com` and `www.example-tulip.com` by issuing following commands:

**Server Side Setup**

```
# software installation
yum install httpd mod_fcgid php-cli

# added cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 in /etc/php.ini
echo "cgi.fix_pathinfo=1" >> /etc/php.ini
echo "PHP_Fix_Pathinfo_Enable 1" >> /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf

# added new users and groups for the two virtual sites
groupadd rose
groupadd tulip
useradd -s /bin/false -d /var/www/rose -m -g rose rose
useradd -s /bin/false -d /var/www/tulip -m -g tulip tulip
chmod 755 /var/www/rose
chmod 755 /var/www/tulip

# create new document root and make them own by respective users
mkdir -p /var/www/rose/web
chown rose:rose /var/www/rose/web
mkdir -p /var/www/tulip/web
chown tulip:tulip /var/www/tulip/web
```

Now since I want to run PHP through SuEXEC, I have done following additional steps of creating a wrapper script for SuEXEC

```
mkdir -p /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/rose
mkdir -p /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/tulip

# inside the wrapper, I added a file (/var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/rose/php-fcgi-starter) 
# with below content:
#!/bin/sh
PHPRC=/etc/
export PHPRC
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=8
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi

# changed the permission
chmod 755 /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/rose/php-fcgi-starter
chown -R rose:rose /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/rose
# above steps are repeated for tulip as well
```

Then finally I added the following content in my httpd.conf file to enable the virtual hosting

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example-rose.com
  ServerAlias example-rose.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example-rose.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/rose/web/
  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    SuexecUserGroup rose rose
    <Directory /var/www/rose/web/>
      Options +ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php
      FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/rose/php-fcgi-starter .php
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>
  ErrorLog /var/www/rose/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/rose/access.log combined
  ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
... similar lines for the second virtual host (Tulip). Cutting short ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted the server and put one index.php file in the web directory with following content : `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

**Local Machine**

In order to test the virtual hosts, I issued following commands from my local machine using `curl`

```
$> curl -v -H "www.example-rose.com" 162.*.35.155/index.php
*   Trying 162.*.35.155...
* Connected to 162.*.35.155 port 80 (#0)
> GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: www.example-rose.com
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 162.*.35.155 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

If I try accessing through web browser instead of `curl` (after creating `/etc/hosts` entry for the domains), I get blank page. No Apache Access log or error log is generated in the server. If I put a static file (instead of php file), I **can** access the static file without any issue. But .php file does not work.

**However**

When I try to `curl` from the **DigitalOcean's server itself** (or from some other server within DigitalOcean's network), I get to see the expected index.php with `phpinfo()` results without any issue. But doesn't work when I try from outside DO's network.

I have done all sorts common troubleshooting (installing, re-installing, checking permissions, checking conf files again and again etc.) and I am at my wit's end now. Next what?

*Please do not answer until you read the full question :)*

Comment: The strange thing here is the missing request entry in the log files. Trusting that you know where to look for the entries this clearly states, that there is _no_ connection to _that_ server. Since the client does not complain about not being able to connect or the connection getting interrupted this points towards an issue on network level. So I suggest two things as next steps: 1. a traceroute to the server to check if you connect to the right server and 2. a network sniffer (tcpdump or wireshark) to monitor packages getting exchanged. I'd expect package loss on network level...

Comment: What browser? My guess is the browser is either not using your `/etc/hosts` for DNS lookups or has a wrongly cached version. My guess is `ping www.example-rose.com` works perfectly too (from the test machine with the wrong browser result). Best guess - add test host entries to your local DNS server - if you have one.

Comment: what are apache versions in both sides?

Comment: @arkascha Yes, that's strange indeed. In fact, this happens only for php files. Static html files are returned perfectly by the virtual host. So `trace route` actually works.

Comment: @Tigger Browser is "Safari". Browser surely got the correct IP as static pages are returned correctly. The issue is only with PHP pages. Also I tried using `-H` flag in `Curl` with same result as browser

Comment: @Stefano Apache is only in the Server side. Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

Comment: So you imply that it is the php engine crashing.Might well be, fastcgi is not that widespread after all. That might also explain the missing request log entry, since that log entry only gets written _after_ the request has been processed (because the return value is added to that entry). So maybe it's time to give that fastcgi server a closer look: 1. _is it running?_ ;-) 2. where does that server write its log to? Any entries _there_? And it might be worth raising its ulimit so that you get a core dump to examine...

Comment: Iknow apache is server side. You said in local it works not in production. Apache changed significantly in version 2.4.* If I remember well. So versions matters. You have said only one version and I asked for both!

Comment: @Stefano That's not what I said :) I said it works when I try to retrieve the page from the command prompt of the server itself by using `curl`. But it does not work from remote machine.

Comment: This may be blocked by firewall, check it's status first.